# How to hide div in Chrome

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have been checking my website across different browsers. I am aware of the ability/need to use browser specific CSS.

Is there a reason (other than the obvious) as to why the `.sidebar` appears in the middle of the profile page in Chrome but not in Firefox? I haven't set it to display on Chrome intentionally and I don't want it to display.

If so, is the best course of action to use `webkit` in my CSS?

The URL is:

[Profile page](http://52.209.186.138/members/gavin/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the sidebar appears at the centre of the page is because you have the property `position: fixed;` on `.sidebar`. You can remove that and Bootstrap will use its own styling.

EDIT: It's recommended that you don't add margins or custom widths on elements using Bootstrap grid-system. You should add those in the child element instead.